# How to fix the "Insufficient pre-allocated space to mmap vdex." issue on Android P

Tags: c#, android, mmap

On the Android P version, our custom Android system encountered a very strange problem. We have a common control APK under system/framework (this APK will support UI consistency of our system, so many system applications will use it), but on Android P, there are occasional probability that various system applications will occur.

The crash problem, after checking, is caused by not finding the class in this APK, but this class does exist in this apk, and will print the "**Insufficient pre-allocated space to mmap vdex.**" log, so try to go Delete the vdex package associated with this apk under `/data/dalvik-cache/arm64`, the problem will be fixed, but why is this problem? Previous versions of Android have not encountered such problems.

Should be determined not to be related to our code, as this apk from Android N

Critical log:
Insufficient pre-allocated space to mmap vdex.

No resource references to update in package com.journeyui.commonui

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljourneyuix/slice/SliceProvider;
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "journeyuix.slice.SliceProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/CommonUILibrary.apk", zip file
>   "/system/framework/org. Apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/system/priv-app/Settings/Settings.apk"],
>   nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/Settings/lib/arm64,
>   /system/priv- App/Settings/Settings.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64,
>   /system/framework/CommonUILibrary.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]

The application crashed because it could not find the type.I hope the app won't crash.

Comment: Any update on this strange issue?

Comment: @KP_ This problem has been avoided by other methods, and the root cause of this problem has not been found.